# Should NpgSql Datetime bind parameters be switching Datetime.Kind value?

Tags: npgsql

I'm using Npgsql.EntityFramework (2.2.7) to interact with a new PostgreSQL (9.6.2) database installed on windows server 2012.  I am experiencing some unexpected behavior while querying the database with parameters of type DateTime. At the time I am supply EF the parameters for the query, they are bound with DateTime.Kind = UTC.  However, when I look at the parameters using an IDbCommandInterceptor, the parameter values are actually bound as DateTime.Kind = Unknown.  This is currently causing issues for me as I use the interceptor to ensure that any dates that are inserted/updated/queried against the database are of Kind = UTC to ensure consistent date storage.  This works fine with an Oracle database using the Oracle-supplied entity framework driver.  I read the documentation at http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html and I was led to believe that the value should be unchanged upon binding.  Is this a bug that the Datetime.Kind is being changed within the npgsql driver?  Or is this expected behavior?  If expected, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should definitely switch to recent version of both Npgsql and the EF6 provider (which has been renamed EntityFramework6.Npgsql), this may go away once you do.

Comment: I apologize,   I didn't realize that the package was renamed!  Thank you for your help.